# Javascript navigation, hover show, unhover hide with timeout, how?

Tags: javascript

I have navigation:

```
<li class="sliding-element zobrazSubMenu">
    <a href="/Antivirusy.html">Antivírusy</a>
    <div class="sub-content">Bla blabla</div>
</li>
<li class="sliding-element zobrazSubMenu">
    <a href="/Virusy.html">Virusy</a>
    <div class="sub-content">Some content</div>
</li>
```

I need to show sub-content div if I hover on the <li> element, but if I leave mouse, I need add some timeout (1sec) to hide sub-content.

And if I hover first <li>, and second <li>, and again rist <li>, before timeout end (1sec), do not hide the first sub-content.

Live example what I want: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/advanced-styling/ the black navigation hover. 
Move mouse to "Vehicles" and then move mouse to "About us" and fast again "Vehicles". This is effect what I dont know.

I need this apply to my custom VERTICAL menu.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Check out their source code. They have a file called jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.2.js that handles the effects of that menu. See how they did it, and morph it to your own needs.

Comment: That file is too strong for me, I want only this one effect. The file contains more settings, I cant find it, and timeout() is not in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use jQuery you can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<li class="sliding-element zobrazSubMenu" onmouseenter="showSubContent(this)" onmouseleave="hideSubContent(this)">
    <a href="/Antivirusy.html">Antivírusy</a>
    <div class="sub-content">Bla blabla</div>
</li>
<li class="sliding-element zobrazSubMenu" onmouseenter="showSubContent(this)" onmouseleave="hideSubContent(this)">
    <a href="/Virusy.html">Virusy</a>
    <div class="sub-content">Some content</div>
</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showSubContent(sender) {

    if (sender.timerHandle === undefined) {
        $(sender).find(".sub-content").show();
    } else {
        clearTimeout(sender.timerHandle);
        sender.timerHandle = undefined;
    }
}

function hideSubContent(sender) {
    sender.timerHandle = setTimeout(function () {
        $(sender).find(".sub-content").hide();
        sender.timerHandle = undefined;
    }, 1000);
}
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VqsV4/)**

Comment: This is not OK, I have this effect too, but if need to show other sub-content only if all other sub-contents if hidden, like in example above. In the dcmegamenu .js file is `$('li',$dcMegaMenuObj).hoverIntent(config);` and I dont know what is hoverIntent.